# autocomplete with image at end of textbox in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, autocomplete, android-image

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/autocomplete_text_view/add_an_autocomplete_text_input/

added auto text successfully, how can i add images dynamically depending on text at the end of text box?
What is the way to add image along with text in autocomplete

Comment: TextView editText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.toStation);

            // Set drawables for left, top, right, and bottom - send 0 for nothing
            editText.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,Resource.Drawable.FavoritesIcon,  0);

Answer (score 0):

TextView editText = FindViewById(Resource.Id.toStation);

```
        // Set drawables for left, top, right, and bottom - send 0 for nothing
        editText.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,Resource.Drawable.FavoritesIcon,  0);
```